# plyer notifications are not visible

Tags: python

I am trying to use plyer in Python to display a notification on screen, on windows, using these lines :

```
from plyer import notification
notification.notify('Localisation :', 'France')
```

I see a small icon appearing here:

[image]

However I don't see the message and nothing appears on screen. I tried to click on the small icon, but it does not open either.

Any fix?

Comment: maybe include a timeout parameter  of 10 or 50 seconds ? (reference): https://towardsdatascience.com/create-desktop-notifier-application-using-python-fb3b7b2c3cf3

Comment: I added a timeout, the same issue

Comment: look down the page to where they create it maybe that will give you a clue?

Comment: I followed the explanation, and according to the examples given my could should work. I might be missing some other configurations ?

Answer (score 0):

Notifications need to be enabled in Windows. That worked for me.
Here is how:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/change-notification-settings-in-windows-8942c744-6198-fe56-4639-34320cf9444e#WindowsVersion=Windows_11

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).